# C++ - передача массива в функцию

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, gcc

Есть несколько функций, которые принимают в качестве параметра массив целых чисел.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// нахождение наибольшего целого числа в массиве        
int FindLargest(int arr[])
{
    int largest = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if ( arr[i] > largest)
        {
            largest = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return largest;
}

// содержатся ли в массиве повторяющиеся элементы
bool ContainsDuplicates(int arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++)
        {
            if (i != j)
            {
                if (arr[i] == arr[j]) return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// содержатся ли в массиве повторяющиеся элементы (ver 2.0)
bool ContainsDuplicates2(int arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (arr.size() - 1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.size(); j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{

}
```

Компилятор выводит следующие ошибки. Не могу понять в чем они заключаются.

```
C:\Users\saibo>gcc algorithms.cpp
algorithms.cpp: In function 'int FindLargest(int*)':
algorithms.cpp:21:26: error: request for member 'max_size' in 'arr', which is of non-class type 'int*'
  for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
                          ^~~~
algorithms.cpp: In function 'bool ContainsDuplicates(int*)':
algorithms.cpp:34:26: error: request for member 'max_size' in 'arr', which is of non-class type 'int*'
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
                          ^~~~
algorithms.cpp:36:26: error: request for member 'max_size' in 'arr', which is of non-class type 'int*'
   for(int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++)
                          ^~~~
algorithms.cpp: In function 'bool ContainsDuplicates2(int*)':
algorithms.cpp:50:27: error: request for member 'max_size' in 'arr', which is of non-class type 'int*'
  for (int i = 0; i < (arr.size() - 1); i++)
                           ^~~~
algorithms.cpp:52:31: error: request for member 'max_size' in 'arr', which is of non-class type 'int*'
   for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.size(); j++)
                               ^~~~
```

Может пишу что-то не так. Буду рад подсказке!

Comment: Вы пишете все не так. Массивы в С++ не являются классами. У них нет и никогда не было никаких методов типа `.size()` и т.п. У массива в С++ невозможно "запросить" размер. Такого понятия в С++ не существует в принципе. Отдельно стоит заметить, что вы что-то недоговариваете. Почему в коде написано `size`, а в ошибке - `max_size`? Вы еще где-то наопределяли каких-то макросов?

Comment: @AnT Прошу простить, по случайности скопировал результат предыдущей компиляции, в которой я указывал не size, а max_size.
Руководствовался я функциями-членами по этой ссылке:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array
В C++ несведущь от слова "Совсем". Только начинаю грызть гранит :)

Comment: Ваша ссылка - про класс `std::array`. У вас в коде не используется `std::array`, а используются обычные голые массивы в стиле С. В принципе, перейти на использование `std::array` - хорошая идея.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`arr` в `int FindLargest(int arr[])` - это не массив, а указатель. (При попытке создать параметр-массив, он автоматически превращается в указатель.)

Указатель не знает размер массива, на который указывает. Вам нужно передавать размер массива как отдельный параметр. (Скажем, `int FindLargest(int arr[], int size)`.)

<sub>И вообще, `.` может применяться только к классам. Ни массивы, ни указатели не являются классами, так что `.size()` никак не мог сработать.</sub>

---

Или, можно вообще отказаться от массивов и использовать `std::vector`. Вот на них `.size()` работает.

Comment: ну не только вектор...

Answer (score 4):

Это вам не Java какая :), это С++ - при передаче массива надо передавать размер отдельно.

Или пользоваться классами C++ типа `vector`, `array`...